# É errado ter as tags header e section e não ter um footer?

Tags: html, html5, estilo-de-codificação

Eu tenho uma aplicação de uma única página, bem simples mesmo, e usei as *tags* `header` e `section`, sem criar um `footer`, pois achei desnecessário.

Há alguma regra ou recomendação sobre isso? Posso utilizar uma *tag* `header` sem necessariamente possuir uma `footer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, elas são completamente independentes, você usa cada uma de acordo com sua necessidade, se não tem um rodapé é só não usar.

Por outro lado você poderia criar um rodapé simples, colocando uma instrução ou colocando o nome da empresa, versão do sistema, algo que não deixe sem nada.

Do ponto de vista técnico é perfeitamente válido, do ponto de vista de *design* seria interessante ter alguma informação útil, só não se sinta obrigado.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicacao, obrigado.

Comment: Ontem eu tava vendo um pouco mais sobre semantica e acho que tinha visto um elemento de texto que pode ser usado dentro do footer pra copyright por exemplo mas nao consigo lembrar, existe mesmo?

Comment: @MoraisVilson é o `<footer>` mesmo, o que o pessoal costuma fazer é por dentro de um `<small>` também, mas isto é estilo apenas. Você pode votar em tudo no site também.